# Cython callback causing memory corruption/segfaults

Tags: callback, pthreads, segmentation-fault, cython

I am interfacing python with a c++ library using cython. I need a callback function that the c++ code can call. I also need to pass a reference to a specific python object to this function. This is all quite clear from the callback demo.

However I get various errors when the callback is called from c++ thread (pthread):

1. Pass function pointer and class/object (as void*) to c++
2. Store the pointers within c++
3. Start new thread (pthread) running a loop

   1. Call function using the stored function pointer and pass back the class pointer (void*)
4. In python: cast void* back to class/object
5. Call a method of above class/object (Error)

Steps 2 and 3 are in c++.

The errors are mostly segmentation faults but sometimes I get complaints about some low level python calls.

I have the exact same code where I create a thread in python and call the callback directly. This works OK. So the callback itself is working.

I do need a separate thread running in c++ since this thread is communicating with hardware and on occasion calling my callback.

I have also triple-checked all the pointers that are being passed around. They point to valid locations.

I suspect there are some problems when using cython classes from a c++ thread..?

I am using Python 2.6.6 on Ubuntu.

So my question is:
Can I manipulate python objects from a non-python thread?
If not, is there a way can make the thread python-compatible? (pthread)

This is the minimal callback that already causes problems when called from c++ thread:

```
cdef int CheckCollision(float* Angles, void* user_data):
    self = <CollisionDetector>user_data
    return self.__sizeof__() # <====== Error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, you must not manipulate Python objects without acquiring GIL in the first place. You must use `PyGILState_Ensure()` + `PyGILState_Release()` (see the [PyGILState_Ensure documentation](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#PyGILState_Ensure))
2. You can ensure that your object will be not deleted by python if you explicitly take the reference, and release it when you're not using it anymore with `Py_INCREF()` and `Py_DECREF()`. If you pass the callback to your c++, and if you don't have a reference taken anymore, maybe your python object is freed, and the crash happen (see the [Py_INCREF documentatation](http://docs.python.org/c-api/refcounting.html?highlight=incref#Py_INCREF)).

Disclamer: i'm not saying this is your issue, just giving you tips to track down the bug :)